# Get .aspx control ID in .js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

**Hello everyone,**

### **(HEAD PART)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ChangeColor1(elementid)
{
document.getElementById(elementid).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/1.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img2.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img3.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url'images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img4.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= imgchange.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/img1.JPG')";
}

function ChangeColor2(elementid) 
{
document.getElementById(elementid).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/1.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img1.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img3.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img4.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= imgchange.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/img2.JPG')";
}

function ChangeColor3(elementid)
{
document.getElementById(elementid).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/1.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img1.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img2.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img4.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= imgchange.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/img3.JPG')";
}
function ChangeColor4(elementid)
{
document.getElementById(elementid).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/1.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img2.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img3.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img1.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage =  "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= imgchange.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/img4.JPG')";
}
</script>
```

### **(BODY PART)**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="img1" runat="server" onmouseover="ChangeColor1(this.id)" 
    style="background-image: url('images/2.jpg')">
</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<td id="img2" runat="server" onmouseover="ChangeColor2(this.id)" 
    style="background image: url('images/2.jpg')">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="img3" runat="server" onmouseover="ChangeColor3(this.id)" 
    style="background-image: url('images/2.jpg')">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="img4" runat="server" onmouseover="ChangeColor4(this.id)" 
    style="background-image: url('images/2.jpg')">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

This code is working fine in .ASPX page.

But when I put this script code in .js file and call it in head part of .ASPX page, this .js file is not working well.

ID=img2, ID=img3, ID=img4 of **td** is not passing in .js file.

How can I pass this all ID in .js file???

Comment: It won't work just if you're using `MasterPages`, because the `IDs` will be changed. You can add a piece of `Javascript` to the `.aspx` file just to declare some variables containing the elements `IDs`. Or, easier, set classes to the elements and use `jQuery` to select them.

Comment: @adil is correct. I think you can make the variables global and access it in Js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On aspx page write

```
<script>
var img1 = '<%= img1.ClientID%>';
var img2= '<%= img2.ClientID%>';
var img3= '<%= img3.ClientID%>';
var img4= '<%= img4.ClientID%>';
var imgchange= '<%= imgchange.ClientID%>';
</script>
```

in .js file do

```
function ChangeColor1(elementid) {
document.getElementById(img1).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/1.jpg')";
document.getElementById(img2).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById(img3).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById(img4).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
}
```

try this it will help you

Comment: Solves the issue, but when the OP ends up with hundreds of cells, a lot of `Javascript` code is necessary to be added.

Comment: The person who posted the question. And although I live in the UK, this doesn't make me a sir. LOL

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ASP.NET will not process your JS file and fill out the placeholders.

One solution is to force the ID to remain static, for example:

```
<td id="img4" runat="server" clientidmode="static" onmouseover="ChangeColor4(this.id)" 
    style="background-image: url('images/2.jpg')">
</td>
```

The `clientidmode="static"` attribute tells ASP.NET not to mangle the ID. Then you don't even need to use the `<%= img1.ClientID%>` at all.